# Workflows custom form

Tags: workflow-activity

I have some requirement. in my project, after workflow is started on list, the custom Form is assigned to 2 persons at a time. if one person is accept the form, automatically the other person loosing the right to accept the form. how to set it.

Please tell me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With the OOTB workflows these are actually Task Forms, and you need to configure the Workflow to send them in Parallel and you can use the "CLAIM TASK" functionality to mark that you are the respondent. In addition (a little variation) you can specify to end workflow on 1st approval/rejection.

If you created your own workflow use same guidelines to set Assigned to for the Task Form and only create a single task. Participants would then use the Claim Task to mark it.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius